# What degree is this palindrome?

Tags: code-golf, string, palindrome

Your task is to determine the palindromic degree of a given non-empty string.

To do this, loop until one of the following conditions are met:

- The string is not a palindrome.
- You encounter a string that has already been encountered.

And do the following:

- If it is a palindrome, add one to the degree.
- Depalindromize.

For example, if I had the string `babababab`, the calculation would go:

```
babababab     1
babab         2
bab           3
ba
```

For the string `zzzzz`, it would go:

```
zzzzz         1
zzz           2
zz            3
z             4
z
```

#### Test cases

```
abc 0
cenea 0
pappap 2
aa 2
aba 1
aaa 3
cccc 3
zzzzz 4
```

Explanation:

```
abc : 0
cenea : 0
pappap -> pap -> pa : 2
aa -> a -> a : 2
aba -> ab : 1
aaa -> aa -> a -> a: 3
cccc -> cc -> c -> c: 3
zzzzz -> zzz -> zz -> z -> z : 4
```

Remember, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the fewest bytes wins.

Comment: To be clear, the unpalindromize a string, you take half of it, including the center if the original had odd length?

Comment: @xnor Yes.-----

Comment: This gives a loop once you get down to length 1, since those un-palindromize to themselves. You should make explicit if you define them to have degree 1.

Comment: Also, I don't understand the test cases. How do you get `cenea -> 1`? `zzzzz -> 4`? You really should iron these things out in the sandbox.

Comment: `zzzzz → zzz → zz → z` so 4 is correct but `cenea` obviously wrong

Comment: I have clarified the question.

Comment: Can the input be the empty string? Looks clear otherwise. I'd suggest the test cases be just the input and outputs for easy copy-pasting, with the derivations shown separately.

Comment: Can you include a longer 1-palindrome (e.g. `abcdedcba`)?

Comment: no restriction on how input is provided?

Comment: @ardnew Nope.--

Answer (score 3):

### Perl, 53 bytes

52 bytes of code + 1 byte for `-p`.

```pl
$\++while s/^((.+).?)(??{reverse$2})$/$1/||s/^.$//}{
```

To run it :

```
perl -pE '$\++while s/^((.+).?)(??{reverse$2})$/$1/||s/^.$//}{' <<< "zzzzz"
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>11</s> 9 bytes

```
ŒHḢ$ƬUƑƤS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJI@HOxapHFsTemzisSXB/x/u2ATkH24/OunhzhlcD3dvOdz@qGlN5P//SYlQqGDMlZiUrGDAlZyal5oIpAsSC4BIwYgrMRFEJCUqGAKZiUB1yUAApKpAQMEEAA)

-2 bytes thanks to [Unrelated String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85334/unrelated-string)!

### How it works

```
ŒHḢ$ƬUƑƤS - Main link. Takes a string S on the left
   $Ƭ     - Until reaching a previously encountered string:
ŒH        -   Split into halves
  Ḣ       -   Take the first one
       Ƥ  - Over each prefix:
     U    -   Reverse each string in the prefix
      Ƒ   -   Does that equal the prefix?
        S - Sum
```

Comment: [As sweet as that `\a` is, -3](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJI@HOxapHFsTemzisSXB/x/u2ATkH24/OunhzhlcD3dvOdz@qGlN5P//SYlQqGDMlZiUrGDAlZyal5oIpAsSC4BIwYgrMRFEJCUqGAKZiUB1yUAApKpAQMEEAA)

Comment: @UnrelatedString Very nice use of `Ƒ` and `U`'s vectorisation!

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 85 bytes

```
f=s=>s[1]?(t=s.slice(0,l=-~s.length/2))==[...s.slice(-l)].reverse().join``?1+f(t):0:1
```

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 58 bytes

```
p[a]=1
p a|reverse a==a=1+p(take(div(1+length a)2)a)
p _=0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 14 bytes

```
[ÐÂÊ#¼g#2ä¬])\
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=W8OQw4LDiiPCvGcjMsOkwqxdKVw&input=enp6eno)

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 56 bytes

```
s=>if(s.reverse==s&&s.size>1)1+h(s.take(s.size/2))else 2
```

requires an assignmentt to a variable with type declaration:

`val f:(String=>Int)=...`

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth - 21  bytes

The case of palindromes never running out really cost me, will look for a better way.

```
.xxK.uhc2NQ)hf!_ITKlK
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.xxK.uhc2NQ%29hf%21_ITKlK&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22babababab%22%0A%27abc%27%0A%27cenea%27%0A%27pappap%27%0A%27aa%27%0A%27aba%27%0A%27aaa%27%0A%27cccc%27%0A%27zzzzz%27&debug=0).

Comment: @ETHproductions i'm not sure if that works, but thanks, I'll look into that

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, <s>94</s> <s>87</s> 77 bytes

The recursive approach... this currently assumes that empty & single letter strings get a score of 1.

```
def P(x,c=0):a=len(x);return c+(a<2)if(x[::-1]!=x)+(a<2)else P(x[:-~a/2],-~c)
```

[**Try it online!**](https://repl.it/EONR/6)

Answer (score 0):

## Java 7,147 bytes

```java
int c(String s,int t){int l=s.length();return l<2?t+1:s.equals(new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString())?c(s.substring(0,l%2>0?l/2+1:l/2),++t):t;}
```

Comment: `new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString()` can be `new StringBuffer(s).reverse()+""` and `l%2>0?l/2+1:l/2` can be `l/2+l%2`. EDIT: `l/2+l%2` can be `-~l/2` instead. So it becomes **128 bytes**.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 17 bytes

```
a!_IQl.u?_IJhc2NJ
```

[Test suite](http://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=a%21_IQl.u%3F_IJhc2NJ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22abc%22%0A%22cenea%22%0A%22pappap%22%0A%22aa%22%0A%22aba%22%0A%22aaa%22%0A%22cccc%22%0A%22zzzzz%22&debug=0)

The previous Pyth answer uses an older version of the language and a significantly different approach.

###### Explanation:

```
a!_IQl.u?_IJhc2NJ   | Full program
a!_IQl.u?_IJhc2NJNQ | with implicit variables filled
--------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .u          Q | Repeat the following until a repeated value is found, collecting the intermediate results, with N starting as Q (input):
           Jhc2N    |  J = the first half of N (longer half is necessary)
        ?_I     JN  |  if J is invariant over reversal (i.e. is a palindrome), N = J, else N = N
     l              | take the length of the resulting list
a                   | subtract
 !_IQ               |  0 if Q is a palindrome, 1 otherwise
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 53 bytes

```python
f=lambda x:2>>len(x)or-~f(x[len(x)//2:])*(x==x[::-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NUy7DoMwDNzzFR6TqpRXp0jhRxCDCUZFSkMEqZR26K@nAcrJ8tl3Z7u3f8y2jnFUBp/9gBBk1TSGLA9iXrLvyEN7bHleyU5ceFAqtFJmZSfiOC9gJkswWZhdihVCMvC0@itQcKQ9DaD2yG11ZvJcMFhofRmf5JFvyaS4ZbKeH2d/9xyU2qzzlxARoWTYayiYJkuY2KFLBRVD3Fq/J9JcM52Q6LMB7j8)

### How it works:

- `2>>len(x)` will give us `1` if `len(x)==1` and `0` if `len(x)>1` (we don't have to treat the case where `x` is the empty string)
- if the previous gives `0` then we recurse with `x[len(x)//2:]` which is the second part of our palindrome (including the center), `-~` we add `1` and multiply by `(x==x[::-1])` to return `0` if it is not a palidrome