# Recursive palindromes

Tags: code-golf, palindrome

A palindrome is a word which is spelled the same backwards and forwards. For example, "racecar" is a palindrome as is "redder". A double palindrome is a palindrome whose halves are also palindromes. For example, "abbabba" is a double palindrome, as the half "abba" is also a palindrome. Similarily, "abaababaaba" is a triple palindrome and so on. Your task is to take a string and return the degree of palindromess. If the string is not a palindrome, return 0.

In order to avoid ambiguity in some edge-cases, the first two letters are guranteed to be different, and the input has at least three letters.

The input string consists entirely of lowercase letters.

## Examples

```
"notapalindrome"
-> 0

"madam"
-> 1

"xyxxxyx"
-> 1

"racecarracecar"
-> 2

"ababababa"
-> 3

"abbaabbaabbaabba"
-> 3
```

Comment: Suggested test case:  `xyxxxyx`, It's a palindrome and its halves *contain* non-trivial palindromes but are not actually palindromes themselves.

Comment: Palindromess? Palindromeness? Palindromosity? Palindromity?

Comment: @DJClayworth Palindromicity?

Comment: I don't find it clear what a triple palindrome is from the description and examples so far (it's not clear how to generalize "halves"), much less higher order palindromes.

Comment: @GregMartin  Okay, the concept of "half". If the string has equal length, the half is just half of the string (ex. "format", a half would be "for" or "mat" ). If the string has odd length, you include the center character (ex. "hello", a half would be "hel" or "llo"). It doesn't matter which half you choose. If one of the halves is a palindrome, then they are identical. Anyways, a triple palindrome is a palindrome, whose halves are double palindromes.

Comment: @DLosc palindromonstrosity  if you ask me

Comment: Very close to [What degree is this palindrome?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/98391/85334), aside from the precautions against trivial palindromes.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 41 bytes

```python
f=lambda s:s==s[::-1]and-~f(s[len(s)/2:])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU3NasMwDL77KXSrA03XZjeD@yKlByV2mMF/SBpbL3v1zC5tKUJI359Ub/JV8rRtq42YZofAhq3lizHj6YrZjX@r5kv0WfPwMZnrsIVUCwnwjdVaCGLIHkLu@MDiQjYK4KeQ24P/rX4R78BCwqpZqDko1P09dOAag@jdeN4NQ8u8uUMW/YRdIs/fUZqw6n65U5Wa6SXYV3rLRbBie@CoJA/jGY4qocPU15MiXPyC9BidmxTOj@rws8EZ3/vO/gM)

Simple recursive function. If the string is not a palindrome, returns false instead of 0 (which I think is allowed for Python).

Comment: First I ever heard of ~ tbh... I suppose you could add 0 to the result to cast it to int `f=lambda s:0+(s==s[::-1]and-~f(s[len(s)/2:]))`

Comment: @airstrike No need, False is treated as 0 for Python. See [meta discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9064/92237).
`~x` is `-x-1`, so it's a common trick to use it for increment/decrement (e.g. `-~x == x+1` and `~-x == x-1`). The advantage is you can save a whitespace before the expression.

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
←VS≠↔¡o←½
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fG6zzqKnx0Lb/j9omhAU/6lzwqG3KoYX5QN6hvf///8/LL0ksSMzJzEspys9N5cpNTEnM5SpKTE5NTiyCUlyJSVAIZCUlImMA)

Longer recursion: `?K0ö→₀←½S≠↔`

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
‡Ḃ=‡½hŀL
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigKHhuII94oChwr1oxYBMIiwiIiwiYWJhYmFiYWJhIl0=)

```
‡  ‡  ŀ  # Collect until false
 Ḃ=      # Is a palindrome
    ½h   # Get first half (rounded up)

       L # Get length
```

Answer (score 3):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 21 bytes

```
{≡⌽?1+↑˜⌈÷⟜2≠;0}
```

Anonymous function that takes a string and returns an integer. [Run it online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAge/CdlaniiaHijL3wnZWpPzEr8J2VivCdlanihpHLnOKMiMO34p+cMuKJoPCdlak7MH0KCkbCqCDin6gibm9wZSIsICJtYWRhbSIsICJ4eXh4eHl4IiwgInJhY2VjYXJyYWNlY2FyIiwgImFiYWJhYmFiYSLin6k=)

#### Explanation

```
{≡⌽?1+↑˜⌈÷⟜2≠;0}
{                     }  Define a block function
      ?                  If:
   ⌽                      The argument, reversed
 ≡                         is the same as the argument
                         Then (the argument is a palindrome):
                  ≠       Length of the argument
              ÷⟜2          Divided by 2
             ⌈             Rounded up
          ↑˜              Take that many characters from the argument
                          Recurse
       1+                  Add 1 to the result of the recursive call
                    ;    Else (the argument is not a palindrome):
                     0     0
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 61 bytes

Or **[R](https://www.r-project.org/)>=4.1, 54 bytes** by replacing the word `function` with a `\`.

```r
f=function(x)"if"(any(x-rev(x)),0,1+f(x[1:((sum(x|1)+1)/2)]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYpBCsIwEEX3nkLiZoZWbOpGBA/g3p24mKYJBExSYiIRvHsssQsj84cP/z2f1WmOilYE7SwkZFoxIPuCtPXyOQ/Ydi1vFKQrPwI8ooH05thw3PV4Q8wKYlCHizvbAMy6QBPdtR29M5IhrjfdqjIMjWQK4DXwJKQgv1Qx@tqgYbkC9/9woN//OvkD)

I hate and am ashamed of the part taking first half of the input, but couldn't think of something better...

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 101 bytes

```java
s->{int r=0;for(;s.contains(new StringBuffer(s).reverse());r++)s=s.substring(s.length()/2);return r;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##TZBNb4MwDIbv/RUWp0Ss2bRjUXfYzuulx6oHE0xHB6GyTdeq4rezQNmHIsfJayfvIx/xjMtj8Tn4GkXgHatwWwBUQYlL9ASb8ToJ4M1WuQoHEJtFsV/ETRS18rCBAOtBli@3sZHXT1nZssnE@TZo/FNMoC@4P3/typLYiHVMZ2IhY23GaWplLU66XKYuI66mcNAPYx@fY5204wCc9UM2@p66vI6@s/25rQpoos9MuNsD2jv4yDFjK4m@oRCs4I9mt78loVU8YV2FgtuGkoekwQKbmDlOwCPPKQqYz2s65/g/onS5Xi4xkt5O3gDbqyg1ru3UnaKb1sH8UKTJCpI0OP@r2Hms/fAN)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->{          // Method with String parameter and integer return-type
  int r=0;    //  Result-integer, starting at 0
  for(;s.contains(new StringBuffer(s).reverse())
              //  Loop as long as the String is a palindrome:
     ;r++)    //    After every iteration: Increase the result by 1
    s=        //   Replace the String with:
      s.substring(s.length()/2);
              //    Its second halve; substring at index-range [length//2,length)
  return r;}  //  After the loop, return the result
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŒHḢ$ŒḂÐ¿L’
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of characters that yields an integer.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJI@HOxapHJ30cEfT4QmH9vs8apj5////xKQkBAIA)**

So many 2 byte instructions:(

#### How?

```
ŒHḢ$ŒḂÐ¿L’ - Link: list of characters, S
      Ð¿   - collect up input values while...
    ŒḂ     - ...condition: is a palindrome?
   $       - ...next input: last two links as a monad:
ŒH         -      split into halves (first 1 longer if odd length)
  Ḣ        -      head
        L  - length
         ’ - decrement
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to a clever observation from [Unrelated String](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85334/unrelated-string)*

```
↔?ḍt↰<|∧0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//1HbFPuHO3pLHrVtsKl51LHc4P9/pYrKCiBS@h8BAA)

Alternate 9-byte solution: `↔?ḍt↰<.∨0` ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//1HbFPuHO3pLHrVtsNF71LHC4P9/pYrKCiBS@h8BAA))

#### Explanation

```
↔?ḍt↰<|∧0
↔          The input reversed
 ?         is the same as the input
  ḍ        Split into two halves
   t       Take the second half (which is the longer one if they aren't the same)
    ↰      Recurse
     <     First integer greater than the result of the recursive call
      |    If the preceding part failed (because the input isn't a palindrome):
       ∧   Break unification with the input
        0  and set the output to 0
```

Comment: If you're willing to let eventual labeling do some of the work, [`+₁` can be golfed to `<`](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3w/1HbFPuHO3pLgKI2NY86lhv8/x@tlJdfkliQmJOZl1KUn5uqpKOUm5iSmAukKyorgAjIABqcmpxYBKWAAolJUAhmJyUiY6VYAA)

Comment: @UnrelatedString Oh, very nice! TBH I still have difficulty guessing when I have to spell stuff out and when Brachylog will automatically do the thing that I want for me.

Comment: Come to think of it, I thought to try `<` because I had just tried removing the trailing 0 (letting the output remain unbound), and I can't say I'm surprised that didn't work: since there's no real minimum it's able to label all outputs to 0, but what's really weird is that if you use the I/O style in your TIO link it seems to actually consistently land the output at 1 less than intended instead. CLP(FD) never fails to be enigmatic...

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 51 bytes

```
v s|s/=reverse s=0|0<1=1+v(take(div(1+length s)2)s)
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##TYjBCsMgEER/ZZEelBQSe65fUnrYxKWRqJFd8ZR/t4TmUIbhzZsVZaMYe28gh4yOqRELgbjpmJ7W2aHpihtpH5q2Q6T8qSuIeRgxPWHIrnDI9ZawQIOXynvFgjFkz3sidQeV0GM6B@NCC/KF88H5yk9m/K969y8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 36 bytes

```
+m`^((.)+.?)(?<-2>\2)+(?(2)^)$
$1¶
¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wXzs3IU5DQ09TW89eU8PeRtfILsZIU1vDXsNIM05ThUvF8NA2rkPb/v/Pyy9JLEjMycxLKcrPTeXKTUxJzOUqSkxOTU4sglJciUlQCGQlJSJjAA) Link includes test cases. Accepts a double letter as a palindrome but not a single letter. Explanation:

```
+`
```

Repeat until no more matches can be made:

```
m`^((.)+.?)
```

Match the first half (including the middle character where relevant) of the palindrome, ...

```
(?<-2>\2)+(?(2)^)$
```

... then match the characters captured by capture group 2 in reverse, popping as we go, until there are none left, and...

```
$1¶
```

... replace the second half of the palindrome with a newline.

```
¶
```

Count the number of newlines.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 20 bytes

```
Ｗ⁼θ⮌θ«≔∕⁺θψ²θ⊞υω»ＩＬυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYyxCgMhEETr8yssVzBN2qtCki6F5A8Ws5yCGHTVI4R8@0ZCimF4zGN8wOqfmET2EBNpuJaOiaFYfadBlQmKMUa/1XJijluGSxzxQeBS/1kvY/VxpphVLa5zgG71PuGjXI25wRm5wY3y1uY0r1aRip481n/JYaQv) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｗ⁼θ⮌θ«
```

Repeat while the word equals its reverse...

```
≔∕⁺θψ²θ
```

... append a character, then halve its length, so that odd lengths get rounded up, and...

```
⊞υω
```

... keep track of how many times the loop executed.

```
»ＩＬυ
```

Output the final number of loops.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 57 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>n==[...n].reverse().join``&&f(n.slice(n.length/2))+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYrBCsMgEETv/ZBEKd3S3u2PlEI2uqYGsxtU8vsmhxxKkWF4MPNm3DDbFNZyY3FUqzdsXmzMGwD4A4k2SpmUhlkCD0PXecWQY7B0MBJP5Xt/an19VCucJRJEmZRXPUvBFWNgl2ShXuvLn7Cgw6WxJ7RkMZ1oCDieaX4j/vZQ6g4)

A port of Surculose Sputum's Python answer (I couldn't find any other shorter way). Replace `&&` with `?` and add `:0` at the end of the program to make it return 0 in cases where it currently returns `false`, for an extra byte.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
[ÐRÊ#2äн}N
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/@vCEoMNdykaHl1zYW@v3/39iEhQCAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/6MMTgg53KRsdXnJhb63ff53/0Up5@SWJBYk5mXkpRfm5qUo6SrmJKYm5QLooMTk1ObEISgEFEpOgEMxOSkTGQKGKyooKIFaKBQA).

**Explanation:**

```python
[      # Loop indefinitely:
 Ð     #  Triplicate the current string
       #  (which will be the implicit input in the first iteration)
  R    #  Reverse the top copy
   Ê   #  Pop the top two, and check whether they're NOT equal
    #  #  If this is truthy (it's not a palindrome): stop the infinite loop
  2ä   #  Split the string into two equal-sized halves
       #  (if the length is odd, the first string is one char longer)
    н  #  Pop and keep just the first item
}N     # After the infinite loop: push the (last) 0-based loop-index
       # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

Uses the legacy version, because pushing `N` outside of a loop will result in `0` in the new version of 05AB1E.